# Is there a way to access Google Contacts using iPhone?

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, contacts, google-sync

I have all my contacts in Google Contacts, so I was wondering is there anyway I could sync them with the contacts on the phone?

Edit: Now I've set it up properly, however there are still no contacts in my phone! Do I need to do anything else after syncing to get the contacts to my phone?

Edit: For some reason I can read my emails using my phone but still no contacts!

Comment: @Pacerier: the screenshot you want to see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/55QQL.gif

Comment: @Loic Wolff I mean i can't navigate my iphone such that i can see that screen in my iphone..

Comment: how do i go to that screen. i go settings > mail, contacts, calendars > GMail > and I'm stuck there

Comment: That's because you added a Gmail account. You must add an **Exchange**, like Peter told you. Then you'll be able to sync contacts

Comment: he said *Google as Exchange* meaning **Microsoft Exchange**. Go ahead, that's the one.

Comment: @Cawas I've added it properly now. However there's still no contacts!

Comment: If you followed the steps on Peter's link, it's just a matter of waiting a moment so it can sync. If it has been, let's say, 1 hour and it haven't synced yet there are only 3 options: either you have no contacts to sync, there's no internet connection or the setup is not right. It's probably the later.

Comment: @Cawas yes I've waited for more than hours.. Anyway I can use the safari browser so there's internet.. and when i access my google contacts using my laptop there are contacts.. but none in the phone. But I'm sure I've set it up correctly too.. I can even read my emails using the phone but no contacts Help =(

Comment: Just checking... go to **Mail** and press the back button till you're on the first page with "All inboxes", "Accounts", etc. then press simultaneously the home and the top button. It will take a screenshot. Upload this screenshot somewhere and post it here.

Comment: I've got 4 accounts from gmail setup on my iPhone, and 2 are to the same gmail account, one using Exchange. In my case, if exchange were configured wrong, I'd still get e-mails. Know what I'm saying?

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on wrong with your setup without seeing you doing it or seeing all details. Maybe you could send us some screenshots of configuration screens (with your personal details blurred)? You can take screenshot by pressing Home button together with Sleep button at the same time, and then send it from Photos application by email and uploading them somewhere. (Another option is to check your local store with apple stuff ... usually people there can help you there)

Comment: @Loic Wolff http://i.imgur.com/YrQKf.png

Comment: @Cawas what do you mean..?

Comment: @Peter Stibrany 1. http://i.imgur.com/4FgmV.png 2. http://i.imgur.com/HWrCC.png 3. http://i.imgur.com/PoRkA.gif

Comment: Nothing wrong on any of those screenshots, Pacerier. And I meant what Peter said: can't know for sure what's going on but it's highly likely that's something wrong on your end. Can you see your contacts on http://contacts.google.com ? Also you didn't show us the config screen shot that matters the most: http://www.cl.ly/1S0d151O1l340T0U2w3V this is how yours should look like. If you're getting e-mails through it, it's indeed weird that contacts and calendar isn't being properly synced.

Comment: @Cawas how did you get to the screen at http://www.cl.ly/1S0d151O1l340T0U2w3V? I did get to that screen but only when i was doing the sync. after that i couldn't access that screen anymore. Btw in the description I put "Google" is it because of that that its causing me the problem?

Comment: Btw its really weird i could add contacts from my phone's Google group (and it appears in contacts.google.com) but i can't read the existing contacts in contacts.google.com to my iphone..

Comment: Pacerier, from your [3rd screen](http://i.imgur.com/PoRkA.gif) just tap on the "Account [blank]@gmail.com". It should be quite obvious, since it has a little right arrow as any other menu list with more options inside. You mean if you go to the HTTP on Safari from your iPhone, the contacts aren't there? So you're probably using 2 different accounts! :o

Comment: @Cawas ok here's the 4th screen: http://i.imgur.com/5LNUy.gif

Comment: @Cawas i mean there's no contacts here: http://i.imgur.com/MtYOj.png http://imgur.com/axxXZ.png . In the second screen shot, i've added a contact called "Test" and when i visit contacts.google.com in my laptop's browser the "Test" contact appeared. i don't access the safari in my iphone, but when i access contacts.google.com using my browser in my laptop the contacts are there.

Comment: 4th screen looks quite all right too. You are very confusing, Pacerier... But if that last test you've done is as flawless as it seems, I'd say you have to do the [suggested contacts backup (on 2nd requirement step)](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=138740&topic=14252) for a 1st sync - maybe Google Sync can't do that after all. I can't recall in my case if my first time it was synced due to cable sync or over the air, but they do keep in sync over the air.

Comment: Here's another idea: is your **push** enabled?

Comment: @Cawas yep i guess so: 1) http://i.imgur.com/mxj4G.png 2) http://i.imgur.com/S4cYV.png 3) http://i.imgur.com/VAvgy.png 4) http://i.imgur.com/RHmYM.png 5) http://i.imgur.com/ooofx.png 6) http://i.imgur.com/LpRg0.png

Comment: Yeah, it is enabled. If I were in such a case I'd try a different account from someone I could borrow and that works with an iPhone, and try my account on his iPhone, to pinpoint if the issue is on the phone or on the account. Because unlike I pointed about 17 hours ago above, that Google Sync might simply not push everything up after all, I just did this test on my side: I disabled contacts from my exchange account and they all (1252 of 'em) got deleted. Then I simply re-enabled them and slowly they're still sync'ing back. Up to 250 now. I just leave it on Contacts and I can see it happening.

Comment: done 1252 back, over the air. no issues.

Comment: @Cawas btw in this image http://i.imgur.com/LpRg0.png what does it mean if push is not available fetch is used? aren't push and fetch completely different things?

Comment: @Pacerier: Push = service is actively pushing data to your phone. Fetch = phone is periodically fetching data from the service. Manual = phone fetching data from the service only when you run Contacts/Mail/Calendar app.

Comment: As Peter said, push and fetch are different indeed, but complementary. Fetch is basically used on iPhone to save battery life. I only asked about it because google said something about it on the help - though I'm not sure it's anything related to syncing contacts.

Comment: @Peter Stibrany so does it mean manual is best? (since i'll only need my contacts whenever i use those apps that need my contacts right..?

Comment: wow i've just solved this issue. the problem is that we have to shift contacts into the My Contacts folder because Google has no way to sync anything outside that folder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure. On your iPhone, go into Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars, select Add Account... and add Google as Exchange (!!!) account. Using Google as Exchange account allows you to sync calendars and contacts.

See http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=138740&topic=14252

Now, gathering together all info spread around, into a checklist format:

- Google Sync is only supported on Apple iOS versions 3.0 and above, because that's when Microsoft Exchange was implemented and that's the protocol we will use.
- **If** your business, school, or organization uses Google Apps, *your administrator* will first need to enable Google Sync. If you're not, then there is no such setup - it's enabled by default.
- Double check you're using the correct gmail account - many users have more than one gmail, or google apps, with similar mails due to forwarding and often mistake this.
- Be sure to [follow the steps mentioned above](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740). Every configuration has to be done properly and it must lastly look something like this, from `Mail, Contacts, Calendars > [your account] > Exchange Account [your email]`:

[image: iPhone Google Sync Microsoft Exchange]

Comment: IMO, this is by far the best way to sync contacts on the iPhone. +1

Comment: Agreed, seamless two-way syncing of my Google calendar and contact info. More than two-way, really, as I also use it to sync with my iPad. Don't forget that you do have to ***enable Google Sync**, as explained in the article @Peter linked to.

Comment: i can't seem to get it working. its linked already but my contacts are still the same.. I can't see the screen at http://www.google.com/help/hc/images/mobile_138740i_keep_content_en.gif

Comment: @Parcerier, on the Contact app, do you have a "Groups" button on the top left? If so, click on it then you'll see the Gmail contacts group.

Comment: @Loic Wolff I can see the Gmail Contacts group. but there is no contacts within the group!

Comment: @Matthew Frederick . do i need to **enable Google Sync** even if I'm neither a business, school, nor organization?

Comment: Hmm, I thought so, but perhaps not.

Comment: @Pacerier what do you mean by "enable google sync"? I think it's [pretty evident you need that enabled](http://googlemobile.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-sync-now-with-push-gmail-support.html), though I don't know how to even have it disabled.

Comment: @Cawas im not sure if the google sync we are talking about is the same thing. i read it from here: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=135937 `To enable Google Sync for your users:

1) Sign in to your Google Apps administrator control panel.

2) From the menu bar at the top of the page, select Settings.

3) Select Mobile in the left menu.

4) Select the radio button next to Enable Google Sync.

5) Click Save changes.`

Comment: @Pacerier so you're using google apps after all? up there you seem to say you're not. In any case, it should be just a matter of "enabling google sync" then, as you just described.

Comment: @Cawas Huh.. i'm not in any organization / school / etc.. and i don't know if im using google apps. but i do have a google apps account

Comment: @Pacerier Google Apps could well be called "Google Enterprise". That's what it is for. If you don't know if you're using it, you probably are not. But if you mention you have an account there for sure, then there's someone responsible by the domain (which is not gmail or any google's) usually called the administrator, who must be able to enable / disable Google Sync for the domain. The shortest advice I can give you is: **read, dude**.

Comment: @Cawas: I'm not sure ... he also posted this screenshot (http://i.imgur.com/PoRkA.gif), with @gmail.com domain, but it's possible that he is using two different accounts.

Comment: "Not sure" of what, @Peter? As for using two different accounts, I've suggested that already but I hope he did read it and kindly ignored because he'd be using just a single account and he does seem to pay attention at this post at least. But it's well worth it re-enforce this: Pacerier if you have a gmail and a apps account, they are not the same! :o

Comment: @Cawas: sorry for not being clear. I was just thinking that if his email on the screenshot ends with @gmail.com then he is probably not using google apps account. (I bow to your effort here)

Comment: Peter, yeah... I know that, but I didn't account it in. Well noted!

Comment: ok btw guys i only have 1 @gmail.com account so those accounts that i've darkened out all refers to the same account

Comment: @Pacerier so let's not discard the really slim possibility of something broken either on your phone or your google account, and try it in different mediums as I've suggested. Get someone's iPhone who got the contact syncing working and change places: your account on his phone, his account on your phone. That should pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Google has made it easier to do this by implementing CardDAV for iOS5+.

Here's the link: http://support.google.com/mail/answer/2753077?hl=en

Instead of using a Google Exchange account you'll do this:

1. Mail, Contacts, Calendars >>
2. Add Account... >>
3. Other >>
4. Contacts: Add CardDAV Account
5. Server = google.com; user name = [fullEmail]; pw = [gmailPw]; desc =
   [optional].

It worked great for me on an iPhone5 with iOS 6.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

I have had an iPhone since it first came out and have tried all kinds of ways of syncing Google Contact with it. The best by far is [NuevaSync](http://nuevasync.com/). If you update anything on your phone or Google Account it is automatically updated in real time. Great Tool.

Comment: I don't get it. does it mean that natively there's no way to cross-sync our contacts with google? btw do i have to pay for neuvasync?

Comment: The answer above shows you the native way of doing what you need, yet the easier and smarter way would be to use a tool like Neuvasync. It all depends you what you are trying to achieve. For example. I want all my devices to be in sync without having to plug things in and manually sync them. I just want everything to work without having to worry. Neuvasync and simular tools allow this. There are free options.

Comment: I can say samething here, Chuck, I try syncing my google with iPhone since the beginning... but I disagree on the NuevaSync. Back few years ago when I tried it it wasn't anything better than Google's Exchange at all - specially not easier. You don't seem to have tried it, because you cited an advantage which doesn't comply with reality - native Exchange is synced automatically in real time over any connection to the net.